# how to enable memory mapping while reading feather file in c++

Tags: python, c++, pyarrow, apache-arrow, feather

While reading the same feather file in python and in c++,in python, the function
**pyarrow.feather.read_table()** performs expectionally well then the API i am using for c++. When i investigated further, i found out that the main difference is because in python the read_table() API uses a flag named, memory_map(set true by default). When i disable this flag, c++ APIs perform just better than read_table() in python. Now as it suggests,c++ is not using memory_mapping by default, but to improve the performance i want to use it. Please suggest me ways to use memory mapping for c++ i as didn't find any APIs of interest in the documentation available for c++.
The code i am using is -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pyarrow.feather
import time

for i in range(20):
    start_time = time.time()

    table = pyarrow.feather.read_table('data'+str(i + 1)+'.feather')
    end_time = time.time()
    print("Time taken to read file is : ",(end_time - start_time)*1000,"ms")
```

C++ code is -

```
void read_feather_to_table(std::string path,std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> *feather_table){
    std::shared_ptr <arrow::io::RandomAccessFile> input_file = file_system.OpenInputFile(path).ValueOrDie();
    std::shared_ptr <arrow::ipc::feather::Reader> feather_reader = arrow::ipc::feather::Reader::Open(input_file).ValueOrDie();
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    arrow::Status temp_status = feather_reader -> Read(feather_table);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto ms_int = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
    std::cout << "Time taken to read file is : "<< ms_int.count()<< "ms\n";
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`arrow::io::MemoryMappedFile`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/io.html#_CPPv4N5arrow2io16MemoryMappedFileE) instead the filesystem API.  (you can use `arrow::io::MemoryMappedFile::Create` to open a file)  There is no filesystem at the moment that opens memory mapped files.  A `MemoryMappedFile` extends `arrow::io::InputStream` so you can pass it in to `arrow::ipc::feather::Reader::Open`.

Comment: While passing the MemoryMappedFile to arrow::ipc::feather::Reader::Open, there is an error encountered, it says "Not a feather V1 or arrow IPC file". Now it is a feather V2 file, but shouldn't this file be accepted as an arrow IPC file ?

Comment: Also i think the create API cannot be used to open a file, as it creates a new file overwriting the previous one. What i want is to open a local file, so what can we do in this case ?

Comment: Using memory mapping to create a file is a different topic altogether.  Do you expect this file will never be persisted to disk?  In that case can you just use shared buffers?  If you're trying to use memory mapping to persist a file to disk then I wouldn't bother.   You are likely to see any benefit there.

Yes, a file that has been written as an arrow IPC file should be accepted as an IPC file.  I'm not sure why you are getting that error.  You're welcome to ask about it as its own question but we will probably need an example of the contents you are trying to read.